# Manually Import Assets into Database

Tags: assets, migration

So Im working on a site migration that had a lot of images stored in Amazon s3.  I was able to get all those images into craft pretty easily by just pointing at the old S3 server.

The problem seems to come when im trying to use any import plugins they seem to all fail to find the assets because they are all in sub folders. Id make sources for each of the folders but there are more than 350 so id rather not do that.

So I've been in excel all day doing some lookups and i finally have a list of elementIds and the assetIds that go with them and i was going to import them into the database myself but now i cant figure out where they go.  I assumed it was using the craft_relations table but no dice?  Anyone have any insight into how asset->matrixblock field relationships are stored in the database or a better way to get all the images imported?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom plugin to get the job done? If you have the Ids of what needs to be related it should be possible to use crafts internal API to add them